# lettrine in Itemize environment overlapping

Tags: itemize, lettrine

I want to take use of Big letters using the neat lettrine-package

However I have to confess it is not well aligned in itemize-environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item[$\rhd$] \lettrine[lines=2]{T}est

\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me how you want the lettrines lined up with the itemize bullets, but it might look better if you used `\parbox`es for the paragraphs:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text
\setitemize{label=$\rhd$}
\setlength{\DiscardVskip}{\baselineskip}% see comments

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\lettrine[lines=2]{T}{est}. \lipsum[1]}

\item \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\lettrine[lines=2]{A}{nother} test. \lipsum[2]}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: lettrines in parboxes with itemize]

Comment: Hmmm. Works with pdftex, but with luatex and xetex the alignment is off for the second item.

Comment: Hmm. Didn't test that, but it's pretty weird. Using a higher `\DiscardVskip` seems to help: `\setlength{\DiscardVskip}{\baselineskip}` in the preamble?